# Context menu is disabled on localhost on Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, localhost, contextmenu

This is the weirdest bug.

For some reason, the ctrl-click context menu has stopped appearing only on Chrome - localhost. I can view localhost in Safari and get a context menu and I can even view the exact same site I am developing on it's url in Chrome and get a context menu. Any other site I view in Chrome will also generate a context menu.

The context menu stopped appearing recently, it had been working fine up until this point.

I haven't been able to find any information on why this is happening.

Answer (score 0):

I found this help in chrome 
I hope it helps you
Re-enable the possibility to use the context menu on sites that overrides it.
This extension re-enables the context menu.

Indeed, many sites prohibit the right-click on images, pretending to protect their content. I think it is illegitimate.

(This extension is AD supported. If you don't wish to support me you may disable it in the settings.)

Unfortunately, Google Chrome does not have advanced options for what javascript is allowed to do (on the contrary of Konqueror, Opera or firefox). If you think it should, please star (don't add a "me too" comment)

In the meantime, this extension provides a workaround, by resetting the oncontextmenu to its default behaviour on many elements of the page. Oh, as a bonus, it works for Flickr and Youtube html5 videos too!

If a site is not supported, please report it in the bug tracker, not in the comments.
If a site is broken by the extension, please report it in the bug tracker, not in the comments.

However, a nice comment is always welcome :-)

Comment: I'll give it a try, what is the extension?

Answer (score 0):

I think chrome introduced this in 57 or 58 .. A perhaps simpler workaround is to add an entry to your system's hosts file and access your server using that.
i.e.:

`127.0.0.1  server.local`

then, instead of `http://localhost/` , use `http://server.local/` (and/or https, and/or port number, etc. as the case may be)

Bam! Chrome gives you your context menu back!